# Maximum integer length in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, var

I am trying to calculate some long number equations where number variable size cross maximum character size allowed in JavaScript.

Can anyone tell me how to store / use the number variable which is more then its size limit?

Comment: JavaScript numbers are limited by the bits in a 64-bit IEEE floating point number.  There is no 'character size limit'.  Search the web for 'javascript bignum'.

Comment: Depending on the type of operations you're doing, you'll probably want to use a BigInteger library.

Comment: Surely you don't really want to do your equations with *integers*?